# Ask help to understand the following sentence,

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

> It should be observed, of course, **that no school, vocational or not**, is helped by a confusion over its purpose.

The words in bold are where I do not understand. Any kind of help are going to be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: @WS2 Owing to your re-writing of this sentence, I kinda understand this sentence. But I still confused about the grammar, "vocational or not", is this frequently used?

Comment: "vocational or not" is a short way of writing "...no school, **whether it is vocational or not vocational**, is..."  Yes, this is very common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is grammatical and its meaning is not in dispute.

But it lacks concision, and its comprehension would benefit from a bit of reorganisation.

How about: ***Clearly, no school, vocational or otherwise, benefits from confusion as to its purpose***?

Do you really need the *It should be observed that, of course...*? It adds to the verbosity and doesn't seem to say anything important.